# Write cyclic groups of order $p^n$ in terms of simple groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Some say that studying simple groups helps you understand the structure of non-simple groups.
How can I write in terms of simple groups $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$?

Eg. $\mathbb{Z}_9$

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_9$ is the nontrivial extension of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ by $\mathbb{Z}_3$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension.

Comment: The simple groups don't let you write groups of order $p^n$ "in terms of" simple groups, but rather the simple groups that arise yield some characteristics about the group.

Comment: Even $\Bbb Z_4$ is not a semi-direct product of $\Bbb Z_2$ with itself.

Answer (score 2):

The group $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ has a [composition series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_series)
$$1\lhd \mathbb{Z}_{p}\lhd \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}\lhd\cdots\lhd\mathbb{Z}_{p^{n-1}}\lhd\mathbb{Z}_{p^{n}},$$
in which each of the factors $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{i}}/\mathbb{Z}_{p^{i-1}}$ is a simple group of order $p$. This can be easily proved by induction on $n$, using the facts that a $p$-group has non-trivial centre, factoring out by a central subgroup of order $p$, and then using the correspondence theorem to pull back a composition series from from the quotient to one for the original group.

More generally, any finite group has a composition series
$$1\lhd G_{1}\lhd G_{2}\lhd\cdots\lhd G_{n-1}\lhd G_{n},$$
in which each factor  $G_{i}/G_{i-1}$ is simple (perhaps a cyclic group of prime order).

The set of composition factors $G_{i}/G_{i-1}$ is uniquely determined by the group, up to isomorphism and permutation ([Jordan–Hölder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_series)).

Beware that an infinite group (such as $\mathbb{Z}$) may fail to have a composition series.

The importance of this is that any group with a composition series (in particular, any finite group) can be built up, step-wise, from simple groups.  It is, in a sense, an analogue of the Fundamental Theorem of arithmetic, which says that any (positive) integer is (uniquely) a product of primes.  Here, the "primes" are the finite simple groups.  Unfortunately, the problem of determining all the ways in which a finite group can be constructed from simple groups in this way is quite difficult.  This is called the "extension problem".

To appreciate the difficulty, imagine that every group of order $1024$ has essentially the same composition factors (basically, $10$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$), but there are $49487365422$ different groups of order $1024$, up to isomorphism!

Comment: It might be useful to talk about *why* that reveals much of interest about $G$, an area that often leaves me stumped. What does this do for you?